# Boost Python : Having problems importing a module

Tags: c++, python, boost, boost-python

I'm currently trying to use Boost Python to export a class, and then use it in the corresponding the program.

```
/**
    main.cpp
*/
#define BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB
#include <Resource\ZipResourceFile.hpp>
#include <Resource\ResourceCache.hpp>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <iostream>

/* a simple add method, for s & g's */
int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

/* Foo class*/
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int n);
    ~Foo();
    void f();
};

/* Foo ctor, does nothingm just wanted to pass and arg */
Foo::Foo(int n)
{

}

/* destructor */
Foo::~Foo()
{
}

/* f() implementation, calls Foo!!! to cout */
void Foo::f()
{
    std::cout << "Foo!!!" << '\n';
}

/* Boost python module definition */
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(PyBackend)
{
    using namespace boost::python;

    def("add", add);
    class_<Foo>("Foo", init<int>())
        .def("f", &Foo::f);
}



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    PyImport_AppendInittab("PyBackend", init_PyBackend);
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("import PyBackend");
    PyRun_SimpleString("foo = PyBackend.Foo(1)");

    Py_Finalize();

    {
        int n;
        std::cin >> n;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Anyhow, I have no idea where i can find the function init_PyBackend, even though that seems the logical thing I would call if I wasn't using Boost.Python.

The module itself isn't in a seperate DLL, it's compiled all at the same time. Anyway, anyone have any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: In the future, please put any relevant code/errors inline rather than linking to an external site.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks mate! I tried to highlight it all then ctrl-k, but it didn't format it right. How did you get it all nicely formatted.

Comment: Ctrl+K is the right approach, but if that doesn't work there's always the `{}` icon on the toolbar. :-] That being said, it's not clear to me what your question is -- why do care about `init_PyBackend`? What actual issue are you having?

Comment: The issue is that the module doesn't exist until it is initialized, and using boost, I don't know how to exactly initialize it. The other option is to compile the backend (without the main) into a DLL then use that, but for something this simple there has to be a better way. Normally, using the Python C apis, you register an initialization function as shown above, before you run Py_Initialize(), but the one for boost seems to be the wrong function signature.

Comment: Try `initPyBackend`, without the underscore.

Comment: It says unable to find the identifier initPyBackend. Using boost 1.49 and Python 3.2 if that helps out at all.

Comment: Ah, I think in Python 3 the convention changed from `init...` to `PyInit_...` so try `PyInit_PyBackend`. Boost headers are somewhat hard to follow but they seem to confirm it: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/boost/python/module.hpp (and module_init.hpp)

Comment: Dude, that worked! Thank you so much! Please post this as the answer so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The convention for naming the module initialization function is:

- `init***` for Python 2.x (no underscore).
- `PyInit_***` for Python 3.x.

Boost.Python's `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE` macro follows these conventions.

Since you're using Python 3.2, the initialization function of your `PyBackend` module will therefore be called:

`PyInit_PyBackend`.

Note that for modules with names starting with an underscore, like `_sre`, the init functions are `init_sre`/`PyInit__sre` (notice two underscores for Python 3.x).